# Spark incorrectly interpret data type from csv to Double when string ending with 'd'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, read.csv, pyspark-schema

There is a CSV with a column ID (format: 8-digits & "D" at the end).
When reading csv with .option("inferSchema", "true"), it returns the data type as double and trimed the "D".

| ACADEMIC_YEAR_SEM | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2013/1 | 12345678D |
| 2013/1 | 22345678D |
| 2013/2 | 32345678D |

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Nu6.png

Is there any idea (apart from inferSchema=False) to get correct result? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the schema with `.schema` and pass a string with columns and their type separated by commas:

```
df2 = spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").schema("ACADEMIC_YEAR_SEM string, ID string")\
.load("pyspark_sample_data.csv")

+-----------------+--------+
|ACADEMIC_YEAR_SEM|      ID|
+-----------------+--------+
|           2013/1|1234567D|
|           2013/1|2234567D|
|           2013/2|3234567D|
+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks Derek. 
Is there any other option not to specify the schema or specific column name ? The actual scenario to be used is to loop different CSV files with dynamic columns with dynamic naming. it could be sometimes named ID, sometimes named SID etc..

Comment: unfortunately I think your options are limited to either using `inferSchema=False` or specifying the schema because when you use `inferSchema=True`, you are limited to pyspark's best guess as to the column type. if you are not looping through too many csv files, you could have multiple schema strings for each csv, and pass them to .schema each iteration of the loop, or you could try to use another library like `pandas` to better infer the schema of each file and then convert that information into a usable string with something like `str(pd.read_csv(...).dtypes.to_dict())`